# Data Type Conversion leading to NULL values in R

Tags: r, type-conversion, character

**Question**:
I have a dataframe - 372x58 that I am importing. There are specific columns I need to convert from 'factor' data type to 'character'. However,
1) The class and summary for specific column are NULL
2) Once I run the as.character code for the specific column, it shows up as NULL.

**Input**: 
**Case 1**

```
AS_1.2 <- as.data.frame(AS_1.1)
> typeof(AS_1.2)
[1] "list"
> class(AS_1.2)
[1] "data.frame"
> class(AS_1.2$Open_for)
[1] "NULL"
> summary(AS_1.2$Open_for)
Length  Class   Mode 
     0   NULL   NULL
```

**Case 2**

```
install.packages("lubridate")
library("lubridate")

x <- as.character(AS_1.2$Open_for)
cleaned <- gsub("([hms])", "\\U\\1", x, perl=TRUE) # upper case the h, m and s
duration(cleaned)
z <- as.numeric(duration(cleaned), units="hours")
AS_1.2$Open_for <- z
```

**No Error for Case 1
Error for Case 2**

```
> x <- as.character(AS_1.2$Open_for)
> cleaned <- gsub("([hms])", "\\U\\1", x, perl=TRUE) # upper case the h, m and s
> duration(cleaned)
[1] "Duration(0)"
> z <- as.numeric(duration(cleaned), units="hours")
> AS_1.2$Open_for <- z
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Open_for", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 372
>
```

Comment: What function/package are you using to import? One of the main differences is how they deal with strings (i.e. strings as factors = TRUE/FALSE).

Comment: AS_1.2 <- read.csv2(file ="XYZ.csv", head = TRUE, sep=",", row.names = NULL, skipNul = TRUE, na.strings = c("","NA"))

Comment: It looks like "Open_for" isn't a column in AS_1.1. Check the spelling and capitalization in your data frame (`colnames(AS_1.2)`) and hopefully that will clear it all up.

Comment: Thank you @SymbolixAU for editing. Will look into the best practises for posting

Comment: @DanielV - That is not the issue. I looked up both AS_1.1 and 1.2 files side by side, the colnames are exactly same

Comment: I thought read.csv2 was intended for csv files from locale settings where the comma is used as the decimal point. Any particular reason for not using read.csv instead given that you then specify sep = ","?

Comment: I was mistaking checking only the typeof() rather than class() with read.csv() that came out to be "list". Since I am used to seeing it as "data.frame". The name change from AS_0 to AS_1.2 are all desperate attempts to get it to dataframe, only to realize the the "a dataframe is a fancy list"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving most code same, ***using read.table() instead of read.csv2()***

**Output**

```
z <- as.numeric(duration(cleaned), units="hours")

AS_1.2$Open.for <- z

str(AS_1.2$Open.for)
```

num [1:372] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

```
summary(AS_1.2$Open.for)
```

Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max.      NA's 
  0.00056   0.00139   0.02556  17.39000   0.31280 311.10000        35